# core Data deletes data after restarting the application

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, migration

I changed my structure and made a migration (I created a new Model), the data is added and displayed, everything works fine, but when I reload the application, the core data is empty, what's the problem?

```
  static func saveToCoreData(_ words: Words?){

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        coreDataResult(data: [words?.word, words?.translation], completion: { (result, taskObject, context) in
            do {
                let fetchedEntities = try context.fetch(result) as! [Favorite]
                if let _ = fetchedEntities.first?.word {
                    print("the element already have in coreData")
                } else {

                    taskObject?.setValue(words?.word, forKey: "word")
                    taskObject?.setValue(words?.translation, forKey: "translation")
                    taskObject?.setValue(words?.descript, forKey: "wordDesc")
                    taskObject?.setValue(words?.translDesc, forKey: "translDesc")

                    do {
                        try context.save()
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            } catch {}
        })

    }

}

static func coreDataResult(data: [[String?]?]?, completion: @escaping (NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>, Favorite?, NSManagedObjectContext) -> ()){

    guard let w = data?.first, let word = w, let t = data?.last, let transl = t else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Favorite", in: context) else { return }
        guard let taskObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context) as? Favorite else { return }

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "word == %@", word)
        let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "translation == %@", transl)
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Favorite")
        let andPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [predicate, predicate2])

        fetchRequest.predicate = andPredicate
        completion(fetchRequest, taskObject, context)
    }

}
```

**old attributes**
  [image: old Attributes]

**new Attributes**
[image: new Attributes]

**new Model**
[image: new Model]

Comment: You changed the data type of the attribute "word" from String to Transformable. Lightweight migration cannot do this automatically. You need to do that manually.

Comment: You would need to write a migration policy by the looks of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided it

this answer helped me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40662940/8070211

1. create Model (**command + n** -> **Mapping Model** -> **select old model** -> **select new model** -> **add Name and create**)[image]
2. create subClass NSEntityMigrationPolicy

   ```
   class FavoriteEntityMigrationPolicy: NSEntityMigrationPolicy {

      @objc func typeFor(word:String) -> [String] {
          return [word]
      }

   }
   ```
3. **select Model** -> **select entity** -> **add subClass to custom Policy**[image]
4. **select Model** -> **select entity** -> **select value expression** -> **add** `FUNCTION($entityPolicy, "typeForWord:" , $source.word)`
   [image]
5. it is ready